# Spotify getting acces token on a server - is Spotify API that bad?

Tags: python, api, spotify

I have a Python application that calls the Spotify API and then analyses the result (serach about song information and save them in a file). The only problem I got is that there is no way to acquire an authorization token with this poorly implemented API.

Neither the package "spotify" nor spotipy or any other third party library provides me this feature. And obviously if I have a server, I do not run any GUI or so, so I can not see any prompt.

Unfortunately I am not a script kiddie who plays with Node.js on his/her home Windows...

Are there any way to get a fresh token each time without using the fanciest GUI prompt?

```py
headers = {
    "Accept": "application/json",
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    "Authorization": "Bearer TEMPORARY_TOKEN_FROM_SPOTIFY"
}
response = requests.get("https://api.spotify.com/v1/me/player/currently-playing", headers=headers)
```

This is the current code that works the temporary access token from spotify webpage, but it expires really short.

The other problem with the fancypants GUI: If you login with your account, each API request will result in your own user account specific thing, for example, the "now playing" feature.

Comment: [Authorization Code Flow](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/general/guides/authorization-guide/#authorization-code-flow)

Comment: Unfortunately every method starts with "Display scopes and prompt user to login" so that all of the script kiddie can log in with a single click. In my case, this is not an option.

Comment: Thai is not at all how it works.

Answer (score -1):

You could use the Authorisation Code Flow as mentioned and use the Refresh token part of that to renew your tokens that way you only need to log in once, however you could also use the Client Credentials Flow but this does expose your Client Id and Client Secret which is only recommended for server-side applications but doesn't ask for a login but also doesn't access any user specific functionality. You can find out more about the flows available from the [Authorisation Guide](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/general/guides/authorization-guide/)